# Django how to query objects one by one

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have to query an object from a model, this object is called "exercise" and has many fields(title, body, answers, etc.) I need to get "exercise objects" one by one with all their fields, do some rendering on them and give back a pdf of the exercise as result.

The problem is, if I do:

```
exercises = ExerciseModel.objects.all()
```

I get all of them. If I do:

```
some_exercises = ExerciseModel.objects.filter(something=something)
```

I get "some of them" depending on filter. And if i do:

```
 exercise = ExerciseModel.objects.get()
```

I get

> error get() returned more than one exercise

How can I get them one by one? I must be able to use them as input for another function.

Comment: Why can't you iterate through the "all" or "some"?

Comment: Because there are 30.000 exercises and I can't return 30000 pdf everytime, I must get a single arbitrary exercise and do operations only on it

Comment: To get a single instance you need to actually pass some criteria, eg the primary key, to `get()`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`.get()` must return a single object, not a QuerySet instance. If you want to get a single exercise then you must pass a parameter to the `.get` instance. For example, retrieving an object by name would require the following code:

`exercise = ExerciseModel.objects.get(name="an_exercise")`

If you want to iterate through all the objects without actually retrieving a QuerySet containing the objects, you could use the following code:

```
for i in range(Exercise.objects.all().count()):
    exercise = Exercise.objects.get(pk=i)
    ... operate on object ...
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to perform the task on only 1 exercise, use `get()` instead. In such case, you need a criteria to make sure `get()` will return 1 and only 1 result.

Example:

```
ex = ExerciseModel.objects.get(pk=123)
```

From the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#get):

> Returns the object matching the given lookup parameters, which should be in the format described in Field lookups.
>
> **get()** raises `MultipleObjectsReturned` if more than one object was found. The `MultipleObjectsReturned` exception is an attribute of the model class.
>
> **get()** raises a `DoesNotExis`t exception if an object wasn’t found for the given parameters. This exception is an attribute of the model class.

When you have a QuerySet with filters that ensure the underlying SQL request will return only 1 row, you can call `get()` without argument on the QuerySet. This return the row as model instance, instead of returning it as a list containing 1 elemnt.

Original answer:

Both `filter()` and `all()` methods return a [QuerySet](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/) instance. You can iterate on it to perform a task for each "exercise" returned by your request

```
for exercise in ExerciseModel.objects.filter(something=something):
    # ... do what you need on your exercise
```

From the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/):

> A QuerySet is iterable, and it executes its database query the first time you iterate over it. For example, this will print the headline of all entries in the database

Answer (score 0):

What you need is `.iterator()` which will turn a queryset to an iterator:

```
exercises = ExerciseModel.objects.all().iterator()
```

then you get iterate over it in a for loop:

```
for exercise in exercises:
    ...
```

This will improve performance when you have large number of items. However, it has some downsides as well as stated in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#iterator)

Hope it helps!

Comment: First of all thanks for help, I alredy tried this way, but didn't work well, because I have a "pool" of 30k+ exercises and I must get one arbitrary exercise and not all of them one by one, my bad, maybe the question is not so clear

Comment: Not an expert, but it should be: `for exercise in ExerciseModel.objects.iterator(chunk_size=100): ...` it will create an iterator over all the objects but only 100 of them will be in memory at the same time...